# How do I initialize a static std::map?

Tags: c++, dll, stl, stdmap

I've made a message-only window class, and I'm trying to map HWNDs back to the objects with those handles.  I'm trying to do that using a private static `std::map<HWND, CMyClass*>` belonging to the class, like this:

MyClass.h:

```
class CMyClass
{
    ...

private:
    HWND        m_hWnd;
    HINSTANCE   m_hInstance;
    LPCSTR      m_szClassName;

    static std::map<HWND, CMyClass*> s_mapHandles;

    ...
};
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
std::map<HWND, CMyClass*> CMyClass::s_mapHandles;
```

but when I try to add to the map, the program crashes.  I've tried three different forms, and they all give the same error:

```
...
m_hWnd = ::CreateWindowEx(0, m_szClassName, "Message Window", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, m_hInstance, 0);
s_mapHandles.insert(pair<HWND, CMyClass*>(m_hWnd, this));
```

or

```
...
s_mapHandles.insert(s_mapHandles.end(), pair<HWND, CMyClass*>(m_hWnd, this));
```

or even

```
...
s_mapHandles[m_hWnd] = this;
```

In each case, there crash occurs at a call to `_Root()` which tries to return `_Parent(_Myhead)`; `_Parent(_Myhead)` returns `(_Nodepref)(*_Myhead)._Parent` which fails because `_Myhead` is null.

How do I initialise the map, such that its head is non-null and I can insert things without it crashing?  Apologies if I've explained this badly - I'm new to C++.

Comment: Can you post the code where you call insert? also the lines before it?

Comment: From your code, the map is not declared static.

Comment: @Neil: good point.  It is in the original - fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Are you using it from the constructor of another statically initialized object?

Read C++ FAQ Lite - 10.12 [What's the "static initialization order fiasco"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12)

Comment: I don't believe so, but that's an interesting (and horrible) problem that I'll look out for.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialize it at all, it should be initialized by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity. Is the window handle not null? Because if the window handle comes back as null then the insert will fail.

Comment: Only the second time (because it will be a duplicate) - and that will not cause the problem he's asking about.

Comment: The problem happens whether or not the window handle is null.

Answer (score 1):

The original problem may be already solved, but I happen to run in to similar problem (without the static part). I used to have the map inside of a function, then moved it to a class variable. I also got crashes when inserting to the map. It turns out that I needed to delete the all the compiled objects and restart compiling from scratch. Then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My C++ is a little rusty, but I don't think there's any reason for having that line in your .cpp file.  In fact, since it's not a static member, I'm not sure what kind of behavior that would lead to.  But like I said, I'm rusty - I could be missing something.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put 'static' here.  In our code, it is static.

Answer (score 0):

This has probably been solved in the meantime, but just for reference: Here is another solution for the actual problem behind the question: You can store custom data in the GWL_USERDATA field of any Window (I believe using the ::SetWindowLong API function if I remember correctly). If you put your CMyClass pointer in there instead of associating it with the HWND via a map, well, you don't need the map at all, and it is more efficient since all you need to do is typecast the pointer instead of an expensive map lookup.